# having problem with .value and textContent

Tags: javascript, html

This is my daily training and I almost know everything about JS web. but today I head to a problem and that is weird cause I always work with these but Idk why it keeps giving me errors. the error p is `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'` when hovering on `basketTotal.textContent = total` and there is also problem with `.value` and this is also the error for this one `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.` I haven't seen sth like this before. Trying to create a shopping basket just for training.
thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Form Validation</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            * {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            input {
                outline: none;
            }
            .container {
                display: flex;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .first {
                width: 50%;
                margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
            }
            .second {
                margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
                width: 500px;
                height: 250px;
                border: #e6e6e6 2px solid;
                border-radius: .75rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="first">
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif">
                    Your basket :
                </h1><br><br>

                <form action="">
                    <h2>Harry potter series book (new edition) 5$</h2>
                    Quantity : <input type="number" class="hBook" id="hBook" min="0"/><br><br><br>
                    
                    <h2>Clean Code book (new Design) 3$</h2>
                    Quantity : <input type="number" class="cBook" id="cBook" min="0"/><br><br><br>
                    <br><br>

                    <h2>Delivery method :</h2>
                    <h4>
                        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1"/> Post delivery</h4>
                    <h4>
                        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="2"/> Airplane delivery</h4>
                    <h4>
                        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="3"/> Truck delivery</h4>
                    <h4>
                        <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="4"/> Bike delivery</h4>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="second">
                <h4 style="margin-left: 1rem;">Harry potter series book (new edition) : </h4>
                <h4 style="margin-left: 1rem;">Clean Code book (new Design) : </h4>
                <h4 style="margin-left: 1rem;">Delivery method : </h4><br>
                <button type="button" id="calculate" style="margin-left: 1rem;">Submit</button><br>    
                <h1 class="total" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; margin-left: 1rem;">Your total basket : </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/scipt.js">
            //@ts-check

            const basket = () => {
                let hBook = document.querySelector('.hBook').value;
                let cBook = document.querySelector('.cBook').value;
                
                hBook = parseInt(hBook);
                cBook = parseInt(cBook);
                
                let hBook_total = hBook * 5;
                let cBook_total = cBook * 3;
                
                let total = hBook_total + cBook_total;
                
                const calculate = document.querySelector('#calculate');
                const basketTotal = document.querySelector('.total');

                calculate.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    basketTotal.textContent = total
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A script tag can have either code inside as text or an src, but not both. Where does `basket() get called? Note you will only want to get and process the relevant values when the click event occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using TypeScript. Your `total` is a number, but the `.textContent` of an element can only be a string. For TypeScript to understand that what you're doing isn't a mistake, you need to explicitly cast the number to a string when assigning it.

```
const total = String(hBook_total + cBook_total);
```

The other problem is that TypeScript only knows that `document.querySelector('.hBook')` returns an Element, not an HTMLInputElement. In TypeScript syntax, the proper way to indicate to the compiler what you're selecting is to use generics: pass `HTMLInputElement` as a type parameter to `querySelector`.

```
let hBook = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.hBook').value;
let cBook = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.cBook').value;
```

But in order to use this, you need to be writing in a TypeScript proper file - it won't work in JavaScript syntax.

If you want to use TypeScript's type-checking, the standard professional thing to do would be to move the JS into a standalone `.ts` file (allowing you to use TypeScript syntax, such as generic arguments), and have TypeScript analyze the `.ts` file and transpile it to JavaScript. This is the approach I'd highly recommend. It's quite strange to have inline JavaScript in a `<script>` tag that gets analyzed by TypeScript for type correctness.

Another (worse) option is to remove your `//@ts-check` in your JavaScript to remove TypeScript type checking.

Comment: Btw idk how to use TypeScript. I have not learned it yet.

Comment: You are already using TypeScript. The warnings you're getting are TypeScript errors. Either learn how to use TypeScript (which I highly recommend, it makes writing scripts a lot easier), or disable it.

Comment: some one told me this ``@ //ts-check`` and I thought it's useful but I didn't know it's related to TypeScript. anyway I planning on learning TS but still I couldn't solve the ``.value``

Comment: It's marginally useful - much better to either use TypeScript proper, in a `.ts` TypeScript file, or (if you don't know TypeScript at all) to disable TypeScript type-checking.

Comment: Like I said, for the `.value`, either use TypeScript proper and a generic argument when retrieving the value: `document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.hBook').value;` or remove TypeScript type checking entirely by delting the `@ //ts-check`.